# Why does the measured CO2, TVOC and CH2O increase rapidly when I cook/bake?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

I have a device at home that measures $\ce{CO2}$, [TVOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_organic_compound#Indoor_VOCs) (total volatile organic compounds),
and [$\ce{CH2O}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formaldehyde) (formaldehyde) levels, and I conducted similar observations in my friends' house. I noticed a rapid increase in $\ce{CO2}$, TVOC and $\ce{CH2O}$ whenever I bake or cook. I can somewhat comprehend why the $\ce{CO2}$ levels rise, as I suspect it's stored in the water or vegetables, and when I cook them, the $\ce{CO2}$ dissipates.

However, I'm puzzled about the sources of TVOC and $\ce{CH2O}$. Where do these substances originate from?

Edit 1: I use an induction cooking plate (no gas).

Edit 2: I use this monitor https://www.amazon.ca/INKBIRDPLUS-Formaldehyde-Temperature-Multifunctional-350-2000ppm/dp/B097222DTC

Comment: You haven't provided the essential info how you cook/bake. But regardless of the energy is based on fossil fuel or electricity, the is no surprise that heating organic matter releases volatile organics. How do you think the smelling of cooking works?

Comment: CO2 should increase significantly if you are using natural gas, propane, charcoal or wood.  CO2 could increase just from you being in the room.  Yeast and decomposition of baking soda release CO2 also.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I will add it to my question (induction cooking plate)

Comment: We are excellent CO2 emitters; put the CO2 meter in the car and close the windows etc. drive and watch. Smells are VOCs. the formaldehyde detector may lack specificity or as Dave reports it may just be in food. My observations: sitting in room CO2 rises slowly and continuously, gas stove - CO2 rapidly, air quality decreases. Latest device -Radon detector shows distinct difference between a well ventilated and closed house; am trying to workout source and significance.

Comment: Could you list the type of detector you use? Many cheaper detectors report TVOC and eCO2. eCO2 is "effective CO2": calculated CO2 assuming ~400 ppm CO2 baseline + TVOC * a coefficient. This works okay, provided that the sources of CO2 and TVOC in the room are humans (we produce both in a fairly reliable proportion). If that's not the case though, they are completely useless. They are constructed this way because NDIR CO2 sensors are fairly expensive, and TVOC sensors are dirt cheap.

Comment: @AI0867 Thank you for the interesting answer. I added the link to the detector.

Comment: It's expensive enough that it *could* contain a real sensor, but given the reviews, name, and lack of datasheet, I suspect most of the money went into the display and design.

Comment: I've expanded the comment into a real answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Many raw foods naturally contain formaldehyde [according to the Hong Kong Center for Food Safety](https://www.cfs.gov.hk/english/programme/programme_rafs/programme_rafs_fa_02_09.html) and other sources. Dried Shiitake mushrooms have over 100 mg/kg of formaldehyde, for example.

So formaldehyde in cooking can come directly from the food, from high temperature decomposition of the food, from combustion of cooking fuel, and even from unwanted heating of cabinets and other materials near the stove or oven.

The recent article [An Investigation of Concentration and Health Impacts of Aldehydes Associated with Cooking in 29 Residential Buildings](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ina/2023/2463386/) compared frying, grilling and boiling.  This study attempts to quantify what you are reporting.  They find increase in formaldehyde and other aldehyde levels from all these cooking techniques.  Unfortunately they don't limit the variables well.  Different foods are used in each technique.  They report different average levels of aldehydes for each cooking technique even "before" cooking.  They don't separate electric data from natural gas data.  You could definitely improve on this study by controlling these factors and have "blanks" like just heating water or just turning on the stove.  Still, the long reference list gives you lots of other sources concerning what's been done before to study these issues.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question you asked, but it is a possible explanation for the measurements you observed.

### Your measurements may not be reliable

While there are a a lot of things that can be sensed using chips that cost from a few cents up to a dollar, CO2 is not one of them.

#### "Effective CO2"

There are a lot of cheap sensors out there that pretend to measure CO2. The honest ones among them say they measure "effective CO2", the less honest ones do not.

What they measure is TVOC (total volatile organic compounds), which they then multiply by a coefficient, and add it to the baseline atmospheric CO2 concentration to give you a guess as to the local CO2 concentration.

Given that humans breathe out VOCs and CO2 in a roughly constant proportion, this can work as a reasonable proxy, provided there are no other sources of CO2 or VOCs present. Once you spray some window cleaner though, or light a gas burner, the relation becomes completely invalid, and the number is meaningless.

To actually measure CO2 somewhat reliably, you need a Non-Dispersive InfraRed (NDIR) sensor. This is the cheapest sensor that actually measures CO2, rather than a proxy that may or may not be related in your situation.

#### Cheap NDIR

NDIR sensors aren't magic though. They measure absorption of one or more wavelengths of infrared light in a tube. CO2 strongly absorbs some of these, so if you know the density of the gas in the tube (temperature and pressure will give you that cheaply), and you measure the absorption along the length of the tube, you can calculate the required concentration to give you that measurement.

However, there are various other gases that have overlapping absorption bands, and components such as your infrared source, the infrared sensor, the filter and other things, might change their characteristics over time. That means you need to recalibrate periodically, and want to measure multiple wavelengths so you can estimate and subtract out the other gases.

The cheapest NDIR sensors (the component itself, not the product you might build around it) are 10-30 dollars. The ones that measure multiple wavelengths will be more expensive. You ideally want the the automatic recalibration to be done on the sensor itself, as it has the most information available, but that will likely make the sensor more expensive again.

If you only have 1 wavelength, all you can do is "Automatic Baseline Calibration". If the sensor doesn't do this, you can also do it on whatever device reads out the sensor.

##### Automatic Baseline Calibration

Automatic Baseline Calibration (ABC) is basically just picking the lowest value of the last week (or other period) and picking an offset and/or scaling factor to turn that value into 400 ppm.

This assumes that 1) atmospheric CO2 is 400 ppm and 2) the measured area will be empty and well-ventilated enough to approach atmpospheric at least once a week.

These assumptions aren't terrible, but if you're trying to use your sensor to measure a greenhouse, or the variance and/or increase in CO2 in the atmosphere, they're wrong and the sensor is useless.

Also, to do all of this, some part of the device must keep track of these values. With a proper algorithm, this doesn't need to be expensive, but there are probably sensors out there that instead do 'calibration' using a running average of some sort.

### Conclusion

Don't buy cheap CO2 sensors. Don't buy CO2 sensors from no-name brands. If the seller won't tell you how the sensor does something, assume that it doesn't, or does it badly/incorrectly. If the product description proudly proclaims something, but it's just one thing in an incoherent pile of others, it's probably just the marketing department copy-pasting 'keywords' that sell well.

Determine what you want to use your sensor for before you buy it, and make sure it's actually appropriate for that purpose. A single-wavelength NDIR sensor that does ABC is probably fine for measuring whether you're ventilating your house well enough, but it can't tell you whether the CO2 levels outside are higher or lower than a month ago.